# Problemas com o retorno da query no laravel 5

Tags: laravel, query

Ola, estou com problemas na minha função de pesquisa do laravel

```
class PesquisaController extends Controller
{
  public function pesquisaMonitoramento(Request $request, Monitoramento $mot)
  {

    $mot = $mot->newQuery();


        if($request->has('id_mot')){
            $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->get('id_mot'));
        }

        if($request->has('ds_paciente')){
            $mot->where('ID_CD_PACIENTE',$request->get('ds_paciente'));
        }

        if($request->has('ds_convenio')){
            $mot->where('ID_CD_CONVENIO',$request->get('ds_convenio'));
        }


       return $mot->get();
    }

}
```

É uma função bem simples para teste, porem ela não me retorna nada, retorna um json vazio, alguem tem alguma ideia do motivo?

Comment: Dentro de cada `if` você precisa programar `$mot = $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->get('id_mot'));` por isso você não tem resultado.

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso e ainda não obtive os resultados, estranho...

Comment: Dentro de cada if você não atualizou a variável `$mot` com a nova informação de filtro, ou seja, precisa `$mot = $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->get('id_mot'));` atribuir em todas as linhas isso... Apesar que mesmo assim deveria ter retornado algum coisa se sua tabela contiver dados...

Comment: Ja achei a solução, as requests estavam indo vazias, então ele não procurava nada, a questão agora é como evitar que ele envie as requets vazias

Answer (score 0):

Analisando o código, o algoritmo criado está correto,porém tem alguns ajustes que podem te auxiliar.

Caso você esteja passando as informações do request via POST, pode fazer as seguintes alterações:

```
if($request->has('id_mot')){
        $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->get('id_mot'));
```

Pode ser alterado para:

```
if($request->id_mot){
        $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->id_mot);
```

Em seguida, verificando os comentários, para que você consiga validar se o campo está vazio ou não, é possível utilizar a próprio validation do laravel.

Faça dessa forma:

```
public function pesquisaMonitoramento(Request $request, Monitoramento $mot)
```

{

```
$mot = $mot->newQuery();

    if(! empty($request->id_mot)){
        $mot->where('ID_CD_INTERNACAO',$request->get('id_mot'));
    }

    if(! empty($request->ds_paciente)){
        $mot->where('ID_CD_PACIENTE',$request->get('ds_paciente'));
    }

    if(! empty($request->ds_convenio)){
        $mot->where('ID_CD_CONVENIO',$request->get('ds_convenio'));
    }


   return $mot->get();
}
```

A função `empty` é utiliza para verificar se o valor está vazio ou não, caso ainda não funcione você pode trocar para `is_null`, para verificar se o request é nulo.